# Web Developer tools in Midori web browser

Tags: web-development

This might not be the best place, but here i go.

I am thinking of switching to [Midori Web Browser](http://midori-browser.org/), as it is lighter than chromium/chrome/firefox. Currently I am struggling to find any web-dev tools for it.

> Any web-developer toolset for Midori web browser?
>
> I am looking for something similar to FF - Firebug or Chrome - Developer tools

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*For the version currently included in the Ubuntu Repos (0.4.7)*

I was unable to find the shortcut to open the Web-Dev tools, but going to the menu (the cog-like button on the right) and click inspect page. Then it will open a window, which is exactly like chrome/chromium's one (DOH, ITS WEBKIT-BASED!).

Hope this helps someone who is looking on the net for something similar to this.

*For the newer version (0.5.7):*

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - Which is the default in chrome(and I think in FF)

> NOTE: The versions mentioned above are up to date for the current
>   date.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to add an answer, but `right-click - Inspect Element` will also get you there

Answer (score 1):

You might try this solution: https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite. This will allow you to add the lite version through a javascript tag include.